# What kind of (modular) patch panel do these conectors fit into?

Tags: networking, hardware, ethernet

We recently moved into a new office, inheriting all cabling installed by the previous tenants. Right now there is a bundle of 30 network cables which look like they belong into a patch panel. I found out that there are a lot of providers selling what they call modular patch panels.

Does anyone know what vendor these connectors fit into?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know that is know as a RJ45 [*"Keystone Jack or Module"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystone_module) and the size is standardised with a rectangular face of 14.5 mm wide by 16.0 mm high. It should fit in both wall plates and modular patch panels regardless of vendor...

Comment: Thanks. Our jacks seem to be missing the plastic tabs which I have seen on all pictures. But the width and height are correct, so I guess they will fit.

Comment: It looks almost as if that blue tab sitting on the top of the keystone is intended wrap around the top of a slot in a patch panel and act as a retainer. I.e. you insert the keystone from the back at an angle, slide up and so the panel fits into that little slit and then rotate the keystone to a horizontal position.